# Is there any way to host R shiny apps with shinyapps.io with single sign-on authentication (SAML2.0 or openID connect)?

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, rstudio, single-sign-on

As part of project's requirement, we are expected to host/deploy R Shiny apps and Markdown documents that must be accessible by the organization's globally distributed users, non-users with the help of single sign-on authentication (openID connect or SAML2.0) and also available for the public.

My working proficiency is more towards data science using R and fairly new to building/hosting shiny apps. However, I've done my homework, researching server types such as shiny pro, shinyapps.io and shinyproxy.io that are available open-source as well as premium versions. I found that my requirement can be fulfilled with the steps mentioned in this link: https://www.shinyproxy.io/configuration/#openid-connect-oidc. Additionally, https://www.bjoern-hartmann.de/post/learn-how-to-dockerize-a-shinyapp-in-7-steps/ also explains the dockerized solution in detail. However, the solution is an IAAS, involves maintenance and skill, which is a downside in our scenario.

Here's the sample app I would like to host for testing purpose:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(rsconnect)

# Defining UI for application
ui =  fluidPage(titlePanel("Sample Template"),
                sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                    radioButtons(
                        inputId  = "characterstic",
                        label = "Kindly select a column to check the distribution and summary",
                        choices = c(
                            "Fertility" = "Fertility",
                            "Agriculture" = "Agriculture",
                            "Examination" = "Examination",
                            "Education" = "Education",
                            "Catholic" = "Catholic",
                            "Infant Mortality Rare"="Infant.Mortality"
                        ),
                        selected = "Fertility"
                    )
                ),
                mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("Histogram", plotOutput("myhist")),
                    tabPanel("Summary",
                            fluidRow("Summary", column(12, verbatimTextOutput("mysummary1"))),
                            fluidRow("Structure", column(12, verbatimTextOutput("mysummary2")))),
                    tabPanel("Boxplot", plotOutput("myplot"))

                ))))

# Defining server logic
server = function(input, output) {
    char = reactive({
        switch(
            input$characterstic,
            "Fertility" = "Fertility",
            "Agriculture" = "Agriculture",
            "Examination" = "Examination",
            "Education" = "Education",
            "Catholic" = "Catholic",
            "Infant.Mortality"="Infant.Mortality"
        )
    })
    output$mysummary1 = renderPrint({
        summary(swiss[, input$characterstic])
    })
    output$mysummary2 = renderPrint({
        str(swiss[, input$characterstic])
    })

    output$myplot  = renderPlot({
        boxplot(swiss[, input$characterstic], main = paste("Boxplot of",input$characterstic), horizontal = TRUE, axes = FALSE, staplewex = 1)
        text(x=fivenum(swiss[, input$characterstic]), labels =fivenum(swiss[, input$characterstic]), y=1.25)
    })

    output$myhist  = renderPlot({
        hist(
            swiss[, char()],
            xlab = input$characterstic,
            main = paste("Histogram of", input$characterstic)
        )
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With the help of `rsconnect::setAccountInfo` and `rsconnect::deployApp` functions, the app is hosted on shinyapps.io cloud account. However, sso authentication is provided thru google/github/shinyapps.io by default (https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/authentication-and-user-management.html#user-authentication)
Is there any way to authenticate using the organization's OpenID identity (SAML2.0 or openID connect)? I couldn't find any resources or articles that can achieve this requirement.

Your inputs are valuable and appreciate your suggestions in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but It is supported for [Rstudio Connect](https://blog.rstudio.com/2019/05/14/introducing-saml-in-rstudio-connect/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I've scheduled a call with Rstudio sales team.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use Shinyproxy and Keycloak. Keycloak is very powerful.

```
https://www.shinyproxy.io/configuration/#single-sign-on-keycloak

https://www.keycloak.org/

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/
```